# Wireguard route between subnets stopped working

Tags: vpn, routing, wireguard

I had a working wireguard setup, but I changed something and now I can't figure out why it's not working. I have a VPS server in the cloud  and two remote clients and I want to route between them.

My config is:

**Client A:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.9.5/24
PrivateKey = eN

PostUp= iptables -w -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE
PostDown= iptables -w -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = Xh
AllowedIPs = 192.168.9.1/32, 192.168.2.0/24
Endpoint = 168.:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

$ping 192.168.9.1: OK
$ping 192.168.2.x: NOT OK
```

**-=[VPS - CLOUD SERVER]=-**

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.9.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = kGbGSC
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
[Peer]
#Client B
PublicKey = oj
AllowedIPs = 192.168.9.4/32, 192.168.2.0/24
[Peer]
#Client A
PublicKey = uP
AllowedIPs = 192.168.9.5/32, 192.168.1.0/24

$ping 192.168.1.x : OK
$ping 192.168.2.x : OK
$ping 192.168.9.4 and 9.5: OK
```

---

**Client B:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.9.4/24
PrivateKey = gO

PostUp= iptables -w -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE
PostDown= iptables -w -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -w -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE


[Peer]
PublicKey = Xh
AllowedIPs = 192.168.9.1/32, 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = 168.:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

$ping 192.168.9.1: OK
$ping 192.168.1.X: NOT OK
```

From server I can ping both clients with their original subnet, but not client to client. It worked before, I do not know what I changed that it stopped working.

While pinging from client the another (non working) client, on server I see:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -nni wg0  icmp -vv
tcpdump: listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
08:20:49.027878 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51706, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.9.5 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1, length 64
08:20:49.027976 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 51706, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.9.5 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1, length 64
```

and the result is timeout.

Comment: You may want to show the results of a  traceroute and also the routing tables on the various machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

is not enough, because we are not routing client -> server -> internet, but client -> server -> client

I added:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and it is working now.